# unable to trigger notification based on geofence

Tags: android, location, android-notifications, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm trying to build an application that triggers notification based on geofence(s), I've managed to create geofences but for some reasons the notification doesn't show up. I'd appreciate if someone could help me out.I've used a debugger on the below code and I think the intent service isn't triggered at all.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Button mAddGeofencesButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAddGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_geofences_button);
    // Empty list for storing geofences.
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

    // Get the geofences used. Geofence data is hard coded in this sample.
    populateGeofenceList();

    // Kick off the request to build GoogleApiClient.
    buildGoogleApiClient();

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

public void populateGeofenceList() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
                .setCircularRegion(
                        entry.getValue().latitude,
                        entry.getValue().longitude,
                        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.d("Connected","Google");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Do something with result.getErrorCode());
    Log.d("Not Connected","Google");
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google API Client not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
        // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
    }
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the
    //same pending intent back when calling addgeoFences()
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
public void onResult(Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Geofences Added",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();
    } else {
        // Get the status code for the error and log it using a user-friendly message.
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Constants {

public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS = 60 * 60 * 1000;
public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 500;

public static final HashMap<String, LatLng> LANDMARKS = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
static {
    // San Francisco International Airport.
    LANDMARKS.put("Mamagato", new LatLng(17.4101080, 78.4402424));

    // Googleplex.
    LANDMARKS.put("Muffakham jah", new LatLng(17.4282648, 78.442848));

    // Test
    LANDMARKS.put("Deccan", new LatLng(17.3845578, 78.4649667));

    LANDMARKS.put("Osmania", new LatLng(17.4180039, 78.5273363));
    LANDMARKS.put("JNTU", new LatLng(17.494568, 78.3920556));
}
```

}

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";

public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
    super(TAG);  // use TAG to name the IntentService worker thread
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (event.hasError()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Error: " + event.getErrorCode());
        return;
    }
    String description = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(event);
    sendNotification(description);
}

private static String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(GeofencingEvent event) {
    String transitionString =
            GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(event.getGeofenceTransition());
    List triggeringIDs = new ArrayList();
    for (Geofence geofence : event.getTriggeringGeofences()) {
        triggeringIDs.add(geofence.getRequestId());
    }
    return String.format("%s: %s", transitionString, TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringIDs));
}

private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
    // Create an explicit content Intent that starts MainActivity.
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class).addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    // Define the notification settings.
    builder.setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
            .setContentText("Click notification to return to App")
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    // Fire and notify the built Notification.
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

}